# Ajax stuff are not running with Django Infinite Scroll

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-templates, django-pagination

I have used [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html) and implemented infinite scrolling in django and that loads the pages.

However my Ajax calls are working only in first page load and are not working in consequent lazy loads. I have [followed this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264940/why-my-ajax-function-are-not-working-on-infinite-scrolling) to using $items.each.... block of code.

But after using the above method, now the waypoint does not load the pages anymore and I am getting stuck on the first page itself(the Ajax call is working). Upon removing the code, the lazy loads is able to load consequent pages. I am using Bootstrap 4 with Django 3. Any suggestions?

I am adding the script that's blocking the lazy load.

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/infinite.min.js' %}"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
      element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
      onBeforePageLoad: function () {
        $('.loading').show();
      },
      onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
        $('.loading').hide();
        $items.each(function(){
            $(this).find('.like').on('click', likecommentevent);
        }
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

**Edit: Alternate update, But this is not what I need**

I tried following alternative to onAfterPageLoad above and the lazy load works. But now the Ajax call is being called twice or more.

```
onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
        $('.loading').hide();
        $('.like').on('click', likecommentevent);
      }
```

Comment: filter in place of find, doesn't work as well

Comment: Is your get post method are working in template after infinite scroll? Im having issues with it. whenever i put get post method in class based view with in finite scroll. infinite loading get stopped. any suggestions?

Comment: @Rohan While using infinite scroll you need to use Ajax for get and post methods.

Comment: @ROHAN Also use the $items to find the controls as shown in my answer.

Comment: as its easy to implement, but also added new work.....ajax stufff

Comment: @ROHAN True. A lot of work comes bundled.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have finally resolved the issue. The calling seems to be very specific upon $items for lazy load to work. PFB the working solution for your reference:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/infinite.min.js' %}"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
      element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
      onBeforePageLoad: function () {
        $('.loading').show();
      },
      onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
        $('.loading').hide();
        $items.find('.like').on('click', likecommentevent);
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/infinite.min.js' %}"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
  element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
  onBeforePageLoad: function () {
    $('.loading').show();
  },
  onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
    $('.loading').hide();
    $items.find('.like').on('click', likecommentevent);
  }
});
});
</script>
```

To further expand on this `likecommentevent` is a value that has an function stored in it. (my jargon is far from professional) Where does `likecommentevent` come from and what does it store? It may look like this: this resembles an upvote/downvote system.

```
var likecommentevent = function(event){

var answerid=$(this).data('answer');
        // Ajax
        $.ajax({
            url:"/save-downvote",
            type:"post",
            data:{
                answerid:answerid,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:"{{csrf_token}}"
            },
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(res){
                var _prevupvote=$(".downvote-count-"+answerid).text();
                if(res.bool==true){
                    $(".downvote-count-"+answerid).text(parseInt(_prevupvote)+1);
                }
            }
        });
 }
```

whatever function you have, store it this way and pass it in `onAfterLoad:function($items){ ##here## }`

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be called after loading page scripts and resources

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".infinite-container").waypoint(function(direction) {
    // your code
    if (direction === 'down') {
        losdMore();
    }
  }   
  function loadMore() {
    console.log("Loading page " );


    $.waypoints('refresh');
}    
});
```

Comment: Did that. But nothing changed.

Comment: You are trying to use library hooks. Make it easier as I wrote

Comment: I tried it but didn't get that right. Can you please try my code above and represent it?